# Is there an right way to override format_date?

Tags: datetime

When attempting to answer [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109192/how-to-translate-custom-date-formats), I started out by looking for a way to override the core function [`format_date()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7).

I came up with nothing.

Searching this highly esteemed site yielded no results.  Google managed to find some more or less (mostly *more*) nasty suggestions for how to hack the core and get away with it (including this [sandbox](https://drupal.org/sandbox/gielfeldt/1546970)).

But I didn't find anything useful.

A typical use case is to replace the strings days with something beyond the scope of the PHP [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format characters.  For instance, all calls to `format_date()` outputting the names of days should return the string: "laundry day" instead of "saturday".

So the question is simply: Does a right way for overriding the core function `format_date` exists?

I'll accept "no", provided the answer also explain *why* no right way of doing this exists.

Comment: Interesting question. can you not use a custom theme function for the date format do something like that? Just curious.

Comment: That is the question!  If you know how to use a custom theme function for the date format, please type it up as an answer. (AFAIK, this function *isn't* themable.)

Comment: if you are using a date field you can use a field preprocess function to do that in template.php. Similarly If you want to show that a node page, you can use a node preprocess function. Is this something that you want to do? From your question it seemed as though you want to override the global format_date function and I don't think you can.

Comment: @awm, yes am looking for a way to override the global `format_date` function. Since Drupal lets you override almost everything, I was hoping I had just overlooked the obvious way to do it, and that some of the experts here knew how to do it.

Comment: @awm Yeah, that is possible, but it can add up to a lot of overrides, and it doesn't scale well one you need to do it to multiple fields and other places timestamps get used.

Comment: from another question on stackoverflow I found out that in php 5.3+ you can mock a built in functions like date() . not sure if this helps but herr is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371854/can-i-mock-time-in-phpunit